# If sentences like "make me understand", "makes me walk" is correct, then how "It makes me motivated to die" is correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, subject-verb-agreement, causative-make

First I like to say that I am not a native speaker and I beg pardon for my ignorance. Usually, I have seen a lot of examples like,

"**It makes me walk**", "**Make me understand**" etc.

This indicates that make/makes + pronoun + Verb(main form).

Today I have seen two sentences which are, "**It makes me motivated to die**" and another one, "**It makes me excited**". On those sentences, they used the Past Participle form.

Can somebody please explain in detail the explanation of it? I would be grateful to him. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can speak of both *making someone do something* (your 'make + pronoun + verb), meaning *cause them to do it* or *force them to do it*

and *making them [adjective]*, meaning *cause them to be in a certain condition.*

"It makes me excited" is the second usage.

Comment: does "motivated to die" sound natural to you?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It's probably not frequently used, but yes, in the right context it would sound perfectly natural.  For example, you're forced to attend a presentational by a motivational speaker by your company.  The speaker asks "Is everyone motivated?", and you lean over to your co-worker and whisper "Yeah, motivated to die"

Comment: One wouldn't normally use *makes me motivated to...*, though. *motivates me to...* does the job better. But the same can't be said of *understand*. That's the whole point of the question I believe.